# Questions about 81st Putnam, Day 1 Question 1

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I'm working through past Putnam questions and solutions and had some confusion about the 81st Putnam, Day 1, Question 1. [Problems](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020.pdf) and [Solutions](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2020s.pdf)

The first problem reads as follows:
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJvO2.png)

And the solution is:
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVcJ.png)

My questions are:

1. How can a number be divisible by $2020$ if it has decimal digits?
2. How can a number have at most $2020$ decimal digits if the number is represented by $(10^a-10^b)/9$? (whose decimal digits extend to infinity)
3. How can a number have a string of consecutive ones followed by a string of consecutive zeros and still satisfy (ii), a string of consecutive zeroes after your $1$s would be infinite (and not affect the value at all, since all numbers have an infinite number of $0$s after the decimal point)

Comment: $\#1$:  by "decimal digits", they simply mean the digits in the usual base $10$ representation.  $\#2$: they are imposing the condition that the number have no more than $2020$ digits.

Comment: $\#3$:  they are saying that the number has the form $1^a0^b$ as a string.  So $1111100000$ would be a candidate, though I don't imagine that it happens to be a multiple of $2020$.

Comment: Is there a reason you are reading Putnam problems and solutions? You might want to ease into math contest problems. Not to be rude, but these are fairly basic questions, and I have no idea what you think you mean by “ whose decimal digits extend to infinity.” We are talking individual integers here, they have finite numbers of digits. Some integers have more than $2020$ digits, some integers have fewer.

Comment: I think you are confusing "decimal digits" - digits in base $10$ - with "digits after the decimal point". In this problem, we are only considering integers, so there are no digits after the decimal point to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the smallest example suggested by the solution:

- if $a=6$ and $b=2$ then $(10^a-10^b)/9 = 111100$ and

1. $111100/2020 =55$, so $111100$ is divisible by $2020$
2. $111100$ has $6$ digits, which is not more than $2020$
3. $111100$ has a string of consecutive ones followed by a string of consecutive zeros

Answer (score 0):

1. $4040$ is divisible by $2020$ and has decimal digits
2. $(10^6 - 10^5)/9 = 100000$
3. $100000$ satisfies 2., as just shown